# CS50w commerce project: 'The bid must be as large as the starting bid, and must be greater than any other bids that have been placed (if any)'?

Tags: python, django, cs50

I have solved this particular problem, but there is something that I noticed and didn't get why was it behaving the way it did.

The below code worked the way I wanted it to work:

```
@login_required
def bid_placed(request,listing_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        recent_bid = Bid(
            Bid_amount = request.POST["bid_amount"],
            listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
        )

        listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
        starting_Bid = listing.Starting_Bid        
        recent_bid_int = int(recent_bid.Bid_amount)
   

        if recent_bid_int > starting_Bid:

            listing.Starting_Bid =  recent_bid_int

            listing.save()
            
            return HttpResponse("Bid SUCCESSFULLY Placed")

        else:
            return HttpResponse("Bid CANNOT be placed")
```

But the below code is NOT working as desired, even though the `starting_Bid` variable has been declared:

```
@login_required
def bid_placed(request,listing_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        recent_bid = Bid(
            Bid_amount = request.POST["bid_amount"],
            listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
        )

        listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
        starting_Bid = listing.Starting_Bid        
        recent_bid_int = int(recent_bid.Bid_amount)
   

        if recent_bid_int > starting_Bid:

            starting_Bid =  recent_bid_int

            listing.save()
            
            return HttpResponse("Bid SUCCESSFULLY Placed")

        else:
            return HttpResponse("Bid CANNOT be placed")
```

Can someone please explain why it might be the case?

Comment: It looks very *odd* to store this into the `Listing`. Normally one would expect to aggregate over the bids.

Comment: Are you expecting changes to the `starting_Bid` variable to be reflected on the `listing.starting_Bid` attribute/field?

Comment: You can even take a look at [cs50 SE](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) if you want. –

Comment: @IainShelvington I am trying to save the value of the `recent_bid_int` in the `Starting_bid` (which has been declared as `starting_Bid = listing.Starting_Bid ` Field of my Listing class.

Comment: @Khan that's not how variables work in Python, when you assign a new value to `starting_Bid` it changes it's reference to a completely different object, nothing will happen to `listing.Starting_Bid`. You have the solution in your first example...

Comment: @IainShelvington, Oh got it, such a silly mistake by me. Thank you so much :)